# std::atomic<> operator++ in MSVC

Tags: c++11, msvcrt

From the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/en-us/library/hh874685.aspx):

> ```
> Ty atomic<Ty>::operator++(int) volatile _NOEXCEPT;
> Ty atomic<Ty>::operator++(int) _NOEXCEPT;
> Ty atomic<Ty>::operator++() volatile _NOEXCEPT;
> Ty atomic<Ty>::operator++() _NOEXCEPT;
> ```
>
> The first two operators return the incremented value; the last two operators return the value **before the increment**.

But, C++11 documentation defines returns from this operators [as](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/operator_arith)

> The value of the atomic variable **after the modification**. Formally, the result of incrementing/decrementing the value immediately preceding the effects of this function in the modification order of *this.

Why MSVC++ compiler use non standard definitions ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a documentation error on MSDN. This test program ([**LIVE**](http://rextester.com/VPTW43426)):

```
#include <atomic>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
void foo(T&& t) {
    std::cout << ++t << '\n';
    std::cout << t++ << '\n';
    std::cout << static_cast<int>(t) << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    foo(0);
    foo(std::atomic<int>{0});
}
```

correctly outputs:

```
1
1
2
1
1
2
```

when compiled by VS2013.